# How the android market make sure that delivered the item after the user billing the money by Android in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

If my app user used in app billing to checkout,then I gain the content to my app user.
How the android market make sure that delivered the item after the user billing the money by Android in app billing, if I failed to gain the content ,how my app user to refund and I get back my content ?

I see the android developer say that:
"In addition, as a best practice, you should not send a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request for a purchased item until you have delivered the item to the user. This way, if your application crashes or something else prevents your application from delivering the product, your application will still receive an IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast intent from Android Market indicating that you need to deliver the product."

I set my app failed to send CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request ,but the order also success and there is no IN_APP_NOTIFY received until I deliver my content.

Comment: The first 2 paragraphs in your question are very clear but the 3rd the 3rd (last) paragraph which seems to describe a problem you're experiencing isn't so clear. Can you elaborate?